# How would I extract an id from multipart/form-data that has many objects

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, multipartform-data

I am sending formData to upload files in my backend, but I cant seem to extract the `file_id` for each key from the data.

This is the relevant part of my `Viewset`'s code:

def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
instance = self.get_object()

```
# If there are no files in the request, delete all the existing files.
if not request.data:
    with transaction.atomic():
        # Delete all files from S3 storage
        files_to_delete = instance.files.all()
        for file in files_to_delete:
            if file.file and file.file.name:
                default_storage.delete(file.file.name)
            if file.thumbnail and file.thumbnail.name:
                default_storage.delete(file.thumbnail.name)
        files_to_delete.delete()

        # After deleting all files, return a response.
    serializer = self.get_serializer(
        instance, data=request.data, partial=False)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

with transaction.atomic():
    # Fetch the current set of file ids
    current_file_ids = set(instance.files.values_list('id', flat=True))
    print(current_file_ids, 'current files')
    keep_file_ids = set()
    for k, v in request.data.items():
        print(f'{k}: {v}')
    files_data = []
    file_keys = [key for key in request.data.keys()
                 if key.startswith('files')]
    for key in file_keys:
        print(file_keys, 'key')
        file_id = request.data.get(key + 'id', None)
        print(file_id, 'file_id')
        print(request.data.get(key + 'is_primary', False)
              == 'true', 'is_primary')
        print(request.data.get(key + 'is_image', False)
              == 'true', 'is_image')
        file_data = {
            'guide': instance.id,
            'is_primary': request.data.get(key + 'is_primary', False) == 'true',
            'is_image': request.data.get(key + 'is_image', False) == 'true',
            'description': request.data.get(key + 'description', ''),
            'name': request.data.get(key + 'name', '')
        }
        print(file_data)
        if file_id is not None:
            # Handle file updates
            file = File.objects.get(id=file_id)
            # Only update allowed fields
            file.is_primary = file_data['is_primary']
            file.description = file_data['description']
            file.name = file_data['name']
            file.save()
            keep_file_ids.add(file.id)  # add file.id instead of file
            print(keep_file_ids, 'after updating')
        else:
            # Handle actual file uploads, if there is a file attached to this key
            if key in request.FILES:
                file_data['file'] = request.FILES[key]
                files_data.append(file_data)
```

This is the request payload, this is a single file but in most cases there would be lots of files, thus the index files[x]:

> -----------------------------418997565113719760241293089974 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[0]id"
>
> 4423c171-430a-4905-a029-ccbf88e921ae
> -----------------------------418997565113719760241293089974 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[0]is_primary"
>
> false
> -----------------------------418997565113719760241293089974 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[0]is_image"
>
> false
> -----------------------------418997565113719760241293089974 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[0]description"
>
> undefined
> -----------------------------418997565113719760241293089974 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[0]name"
>
> Kontoauszug_DE3.pdf
> -----------------------------418997565113719760241293089974--

This are the printed logs after trying it again with another file:

```
{UUID('a092d078-ed37-4891-a42a-fe719956878f')} current files
files[0]id: a092d078-ed37-4891-a42a-fe719956878f
files[0]is_primary: false
files[0]is_image: true
files[0]description: undefined
files[0]name: commercial-development-management_1_.svg
['files[0]id', 'files[0]is_primary', 'files[0]is_image', 'files[0]description', 'files[0]name'] key
None file_id
False is_primary
False is_image
{'guide': UUID('d8e9b29a-7254-4884-bf63-2dfbce19cc82'), 'is_primary': False, 'is_image': False, 'description': '', 'name': ''}
['files[0]id', 'files[0]is_primary', 'files[0]is_image', 'files[0]description', 'files[0]name'] key
None file_id
False is_primary
False is_image
{'guide': UUID('d8e9b29a-7254-4884-bf63-2dfbce19cc82'), 'is_primary': False, 'is_image': False, 'description': '', 'name': ''}
['files[0]id', 'files[0]is_primary', 'files[0]is_image', 'files[0]description', 'files[0]name'] key
None file_id
False is_primary
False is_image
{'guide': UUID('d8e9b29a-7254-4884-bf63-2dfbce19cc82'), 'is_primary': False, 'is_image': False, 'description': '', 'name': ''}
['files[0]id', 'files[0]is_primary', 'files[0]is_image', 'files[0]description', 'files[0]name'] key
None file_id
False is_primary
False is_image
{'guide': UUID('d8e9b29a-7254-4884-bf63-2dfbce19cc82'), 'is_primary': False, 'is_image': False, 'description': '', 'name': ''}
['files[0]id', 'files[0]is_primary', 'files[0]is_image', 'files[0]description', 'files[0]name'] key
None file_id
False is_primary
False is_image
{'guide': UUID('d8e9b29a-7254-4884-bf63-2dfbce19cc82'), 'is_primary': False, 'is_image': False, 'description': '', 'name': ''}
[07/Jun/2023 02:49:52] "PATCH /product/edit_guide/d8e9b29a-7254-4884-bf63-2dfbce19cc82/files HTTP/1.1" 200 737
```

I am trying to extract the `file_id` from keys and use that to modify the file object and to store it in `keep_file_ids`. I have tried different approaches to extract the `id` but none worked.

for example:

```
file_id = request.data.get(f'{key}[id]', None)


file_id = request.data.get(key + '[id]', None)
```

What am I overlooking?

edit:

some more information on how the frontend sends data:

```
 const onSubmit = () => {
    // Create a FormData instance
    console.log(guideDetails.files, "inside");
    const formData = new FormData();

    // Loop over the guideDetails object to set form data
    for (let key in guideDetails) {
      if (key === "files") {
        // If the key is 'files', we append each file object to the form data
        guideDetails[key].forEach((file, index) => {
          // check if the file object has an id (it's an existing file)
          if (file.id) {
            formData.append(`files[${index}]id`, file.id);
          }
          if (!file.id) {
            formData.append(`files[${index}]`, file.file);
          }
          formData.append(`files[${index}]is_primary`, file.is_primary);
          formData.append(`files[${index}]is_image`, file.is_image);
          formData.append(`files[${index}]description`, file.description);
          formData.append(`files[${index}]name`, file.name);
        });
      }
    }

    getAuthorization()
      .patch(`product/edit_guide/${guideDetails.id}/files`, formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch(setGuideDetails(res.data));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // handle error
      });

    Swal.fire({
      title: "Success",
      text: "Guide is edited successfully",
      icon: "success",
      confirmButtonText: "ok",
        });
      };
```

The payload will contain a mix of FILES and non-files, the non-files all have id's in them and a url for file field, and the FILES have file objects for file field.

The only instances where there will be ids sent alongside are the non-Files, the other instances in the payload that don't have id will be having actual FILES.